# use data.table variable in json request

Tags: r, data.table, rjson

I have a basic table that looks like this:

```
df = data.table(id1 = c(22,23,45,78,96,45,21,58), id2 = c(24,84,64,82,84,53,54,85))
```

I'm trying to lookup information in a nested json. A basic request that works with my current json file is the following one :

json$`32`$cat1$cat2`91` , which returns a value.

"32" and "91" are the Ids, and "cat1" and "cat2" are just nested tables (or whatever it is called X) ).

Cat1 and Cat2 will never change, but I do need to replace the Ids with the ones in my df table, to create a new variable in df (which I will call "val"), with the values from the json.

So here is what I tried to do :

```
id1 = as.character(df$id1)
id2 = as.character(df$id2)
```

Now, I want to automatically find the values of all the combinations of id1 and id2 in my df :

```
df$val = json$id1$cat1$cat2$id2
```

Unforntunately, it yields the following error :

```
Warning message : 
In ' [<-.data.table'(x, j = name, value = value) : 
Adding new column 'val' then assigning to NULL (deleting it).
```

I'm sure there is a very simple way to do this, but I could not find an answer :X ...

Thank you very much for your help :),
JB

Comment: dont use `$` but `[[`

Comment: also, don't use `<-` but `:=` to assign to a `data.table`

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) ! I don't think I get it, so considering your comments, how would you rewrite "df$val = json$id1$cat1$cat2$id2" ?

Comment: [[id1]] and [[id2]] instead of $id1 & $id2 ought to do it

Comment: Thanks .
 when using df$val = json[[id1]]$cat1$cat2[[id2]],  I have the following error message :

Error in json[[id1]] : no such index at level 2}

Comment: look at `str(json[[id1]])`

Comment: Again, thanks for helping :) . Just tried df$val = str(json[[id1]])$cat1$cat2[[id2]] , and it unfortunately still does not work

Comment: The error message is : error in json[[id1]] : no such index at level 2

Comment: I also tried just running  str(json[[id1]]), and it also returns  "error in json[[id1]] : no such index at level 2 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found a workaround by making a flat data frame out of my json.

```
df<- data.frame(number = unlist(json))
```